# jQuery delay() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` with an `id` of `dropdown`. I want it to drop down for 5 seconds then go back up again but I can't get the delay to work properly. It comes down but doesn't go back up again. Here is what I have:

```
$('#dropdown').slideDown().delay(5000).('#dropdown').slideUp()
```

Any help much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a second `('#dropdown')` as you're still operating on the same object.

```
$('#dropdown').slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dropdown').slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp()
```

^^ this, you do not need to use the id again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdown").slideUp().delay(1000).slideDown();
```

No need for the second selector.

Comment: there are two answers with the exactly same code posted 6-7 minutes before yours, why did you decide to post this?

Comment: I had begun answering the question less than a minute after the original post, but decided to double-check the code on jsbin before hitting post. :) Due diligence got the best of me.